# StructureMap MVC 3 IDependencyResolver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap

Interface IDependencyResolver has two method GetService and GetServices that i implement like:

```
public class SmDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver {

    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public SmDependencyResolver(IContainer container) {
        _container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType) {
        if (serviceType == null) return null;
        try {
              return serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface
                       ? _container.TryGetInstance(serviceType)
                       : _container.GetInstance(serviceType);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType) {
        return _container.GetAllInstances<object>().Where(s => s.GetType() == serviceType);
    }
}
```

but i nead also the NamedInstace for DependencyResolver.
this ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstace("instanceName"); for container
How can i do that..

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an extension method like I did below. The SmDependencyResolver would need to expose the _container variable as a read property.

```
public static class DependencyResolverExtensions
{
        public static object GetService(this IDependencyResolver resolver, Type serviceType, string instanceName)
        {
            var smResolver = resolver as SmDependencyResolver;

            if (smResolver == null) throw new NotSupportedException();

            return smResolver.Container.GetInstance(serviceType, instanceName);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot retrieve named instances using the IDependencyResolver interface. Access the IContainer directly.